# How can I break the line of a specific word in css? With i18n string

Tags: css

How can I break the line of a specific word in css?

I have the following string and I need the line to break at We'll.

obs: This string is a i18n.

*"Your subscription has ended. We'll have your final invoice available soon."*

"**We'll**" Need to go to the second line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmP58.png)

Comment: put them in saperate <p> tag

Answer (score 1):

With css only it won't be easy, if even possible.

Can you also edit the html?

If so you can add a `<br>` tag before the "*We'll*" to insert a line break at that point.
Something like:

```html
<p>Your subscription has ended.<br>We'll have your final invoice available soon.<p>
```

You can read more about the `<br>` tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

Comment: In my case I cannot insert a <br> tag because it is an i18n string.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just saw that the issue is with an i18n string.

In that case you can use the break-line character `\n` and a `white-space: pre-line` on the css.

Example:

```html
<p class="text">{{string}}</p>
```

```css
.text { white-space: pre-line; }
```

```json
{
 text: "Your subscription has ended.\nWe'll have your final invoice available soon."
}
```

The `white-space` property helps you handle how the white space will be renderered, just take note that breaklines inside the `<p>` tag will be rendered too, so will might need to keep everything on one line in the code

---

You can use a `<br>` like proposed or an `<span>` with a class and `display: block` if the change is only aesthetic and you need something with no semantic value

Example:

HTML

```html
<p>
  Your subscription has ended.
  <span class="br">We'll have your final invoice available soon.</span>
</p>
```

CSS

```css
.br {
  display: block;
}
```